# What is the purpose of .graphqlconfig.yml in AWS amplify?

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-appsync

From inspecting the file I see it holds information about my AppSync endpoint.  However, this raises more questions:

Should this file be in version control?

If this file should be in version control, how do I handle multiple tenants (e.g. dev/prod) who talk to different endpoints?